# How do I change back from MacPorts Python to system default version?

Tags: command-line, macports, python, symlink, leopard

I used MacPorts to install a newer version of Python on my system (10.5.8 PPC), and then used the MacPorts select command to change the default invoked version of Python to the MP version. Now I want to change it back to the system version of Python, but I can't find a command to do so in the documentation.

I know all the MacPorts command did was to change a bunch of links to point at the MP version instead of the system version. Unfortunately I don't know what all the affected files are.

Does anyone know the command to reverse the setting or know the list of affected links that I would have to change?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Macports select can change it back.

The current macports does it using the port select command - older versions had python_select

To see the possible pythons run

```
port select --list python
```

From that list choose the one you want and change to it e.g.

```
sudo port select --set python python25-apple
```

In Monterey  the python??-apple targets don't exist nor does an Apple python2. Thus you can set python to Apple's python but you can set python3 to /usr/bin/python

```
sudo port select --set python3 nil
```

Comment: I ran `sudo port select --set python25-apple`

and got `Error: The 'set' command expects two arguments: <group>, <version>`

Comment: Sorry - I have edited to I think the correct command - I missed the group

Comment: It works!

`Selecting 'python25-apple' for 'python' succeeded. 'python25-apple' is now active.`

Comment: I think the OP wanted to revert `python` to `/usr/bin/python`, the state before running `select`.  To do that, use `sudo port select --set python none`.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak so did setting to python??-apple Although now that seems to have gone.

Comment: I still have `python27-apple` available in `--list`, but choosing that sets it to `/opt/local/bin/python`, whereas `none` reverts to the original `/usr/bin/python`.  This is with Catalina 10.15.7 and `port` 2.7.2.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak Looks like it depends on macOS version as Monterey works as per my addition and the original worked as Im would have tested and by CyberSkull's comment

Comment: Python 2 was removed from macOS in Monterey 12.3. Python 3 comes with Xcode Command line tools, but is not installed in a 'vanilla' macOS installation.