# How can I customize the symlinks that MacPorts creates/deletes when using its `port select --set <group>` command?

Tags: macos, terminal, macports, python, symlink

I use MacPorts to manage certain *nix packages on my Mac. One such Mac has multiple Python versions installed.

When I switch between Python versions, I use a command like:

```
port select --set python python27-apple
```

to set the default `python` to the Python 2.7 that my Mac shipped with from Apple, [as described here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22986/how-do-i-change-back-from-macports-python-to-system-default-version).

However, MacPort's `select` command doesn't change any of the utilities that use `python`, such as `easy_install`.

This means that regardless of which Python is active, the supporting utilities are always the system default ones:

```
bash-3.2$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
bash-3.2$ port select --show python
The currently selected version for 'python' is 'python27'.
bash-3.2$ which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install
bash-3.2$ ls /opt/local/bin/easy_install-*
/opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.7 /opt/local/bin/easy_install-3.4
```

Notice that installing a Python version with MacPorts brings along its `easy_install` command, but switching to that `python` using `port select --set python27` does *not* also set `/opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.7`.

This leads to confusing errors where the wrong version of Python was used to install packages.

Thus, my question:

**How can I instruct MacPorts to make appropriate symlinks for Python's additional utilities, not just the single `python` command?**

Comment: Did you forward your acurate analysis to the macports project: https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets ?

Comment: Not yet, I just figured I had to be missing something. But if I'm not, I will file a ticket. Thanks for the sanity check in any event. :)

Comment: Okay, I added [Ticket:46568](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/46568) to their bug tracker.